# Manipulating Data Frames in Python(Pandas)

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am very new to python and I am trying to work on Pandas Data Frames. I have a DF, when I pass that DF into a CSv file and open it in excel my output is something like this:--

```
Key  Match  Data
sf   111     877    
hd   222     888
kg   Blank   990    
la   Blank     0
```

So for the last 2 rows the data in the column Match is **blank**

Now I have another DF which is something like this:-

```
Key  Match  Data
sf   111     877    
hd   222     888
kg   333     123    
la   444     421
llk  555     421
jk  666      890
```

I want to fill in the blank cells in the 1st DF with the data in the Match column in DF 2, by using the data in the column called **Key**. So that final DF when I convert into CSV will look like:-

```
Key  Match  Data
 sf    111   877    
 hd    222   888    
 kg    333   990    
 la    444     0
```

It will be great if someone can help me out.

Apologies if the question is not framed correctly. I am new to this forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

After loading, I'd  call `map` after setting the index on the second df to perform a lookup:

```
In [100]:
df['Match'] = df['Key'].map(df1.set_index('Key')['Match'])
df

Out[100]:
  Key  Match  Data
0  sf    111   877
1  hd    222   888
2  kg    333   990
3  la    444     0
```

Comment: I just tried this but I am getting some error, not sure what is the issue. Any simpler way to do this? maybe using a for loop or something?

Comment: @vicky1132 You don't want to use for loop with pandas DataFrame. If you want to do something to each row, you can do df.apply(func, axis=1), with func taking a row as argument.

Comment: You'll have to edit your question with data, code and the error

Answer (score 0):

If you can override the Match column of your 1st DataFrame with the one from the second, you can do the following :

```
In [6]: df1 = df1.set_index('Key')

In [7]: df2 = df2.set_index('Key')

In [8]: df1['Match'] = df2['Match']

In [10]: df1
Out[10]: 
     Match  Data
Key             
sf     111   877
hd     222   888
kg     333   990
la     444     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to do this with

**df1['MATCH']=df1.apply(lambda row: getall(row['key'],df,row['MATCH']),axis=1)**

Then I developed the getall() function

**def getall(key,df,match):
    match1 = match

```
if  (math.isnan(match)):
    match1 = str(df.ix[key,'MATCH'][0])
return match1**
```